# Почему конструктор класса не обозначают как void?

Tags: c++, конструктор

Мне известно, что конструктор не возвращает никакого значения, но тогда почему с ним нельзя использовать ключевое слово void, которое как раз таки и дает такое свойство.

Comment: Ответ прост, это синтаксический сахар. На самом деле просто вызывается обычная функция, собственно как и все методы в классах, это просто синтаксический сахар.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Конструктор это **не** стандартная функция. В ней не работают спецификаторы типов **const** , **volatile** и **const volatile** у тех составных членов, у которых ещё не был вызван их конструктор. У конструктора нельзя взять его адрес. Он не может быть сконструирован шаблонами. У него нет имени. Инициализация

```
complex zz = complex(1,2.3);
```

не вызывает функцию с этим именем. Это служебный участок кода, вызываемый при конструирования объекта.

И он не возвращает значения.

Стандарт разрешает декларировать только в форме без возвращаемого типа.

**11.4.4** Constructors **[class.ctor]**

1

A *constructor* is introduced by a declaration whose *declarator* is a function declarator (9.3.3.5) of the form

```
ptr-declarator ( parameter-declaration-clause ) 
  noexcept-specifier opt attribute-specifier-seq opt
```

where the *ptr-declarator* consists solely of an *id-expression*, an optional *attribute-specifier-seq*, and optional surrounding parentheses, and the *id-expression* has one of the following forms:

(1.1)

— in a *member-declaration* that belongs to the *member-specification* of a class or class template but is not a friend declaration (11.9.3), the *id-expression* is the injected-class-name (11.1) of the immediately-enclosing entity or

(1.2)

— in a declaration at namespace scope or in a friend declaration, the *id-expression* is a *qualified-id* that names a constructor (6.5.3.1).

Constructors do not have names. In a constructor declaration, each *decl-specifier* in the optional *decl-specifierseq* shall be **friend**, **inline**, **constexpr**, or an *explicit-specifier*.

```
struct S {
S();
 // declares the constructor
};
S::S() { }
 // defines the constructor
```

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить одну вещь: _Конструктор не имеет возвращаемого значения_, это в плане того что оно скрыто от программиста или его нет вообще, просто где-то читал, что конструктор возвращает объект класса.

Comment: Куда девать ваше возвращаемое значение? При создании куч переменных оно или создаётся или вызовется исключение. При выделении для объекта в куче (свободной памяти) вам вернётся или указатель или исключение.

Comment: смотрите ответ с примером `complex zz = complex(1,2.3);` - это **не** конструктор вызывается.

Comment: "в нем не работают const"...не совсем. Вот такое не компилится `struct Foo { const int a; Foo() {  a = 1; } };`. А вот так можно `struct Foo { const int a; Foo():a{1} { } };`

Comment: They come into effect when the constructor for the most derived object (6.7.2) ends. 
 Вот это прошляпил. @KoVadim

Comment: то есть, в теле конструктора все в порядке, а в списке инициализации можно.

Comment: Нет всё проверил. сразу-же после конца конструктора каждого внутреннего объекта. https://godbolt.org/z/Maqfnrhde

Comment: да, это логично. Хотя иногда хотелось бы, что бы в конструкторе можно было...
`Это служебный участок кода, вызываемый при конструирования объекта.` - думаю, тут лучше сказать "это синтаксический сахар для вызова подходящего оператора new (или другого подходящего способа выделить память) и потом на этой памяти вызывается конструктор, который создает в ней объект (потому что с этого времени объект начинает "существовать"). Да, сейчас и malloc так умеет, но...

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно как-то различить компилятору функцию от конструктора
2. У конструкторов нету возвращаемого значения. Это объясняется тем, что конструктор автоматически вызывается системой, и, следовательно, не существует вызывающей программы или функции, которой конструктор мог бы возвратить значение.